# Logging in inside iOS 6 Setting

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios6

In iPhone with iOS 6, I noticed that you can login directly in the iOS Settings of Facebook. Can this be done in normal apps?

[image: iOS 6 Facebook App]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know - no. Facebook support was added in iOS 6 by Apple and that is why Facebook login page can be found in Settings.